# How to get a certain number of words from a website in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, discord.py

i want to fetch data from cheat.sh using the requests lib and the discord.py lib....but since discord only allows 2000 characters at length to send at a time, i want to fetch only a certain number of words/digits/newline like 1800. how can i do so?

a small bit of code example showing my idea

```py
import requests

url = "https://cheat.sh/python/string+annotations" #this gets the docs of string annotation in python

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text # This gives approximately 2403 words...but i want to get only 1809 words
print(data)
```

Comment: use `response.text[:1800]` to get the first 1800 or less in the response.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import requests

 url = "https://cheat.sh/python/string+annotations" #this gets the docs of string 
 annotation in python

 response = requests.get(url)
 data = response.text[:1800]
 print(data)
```

> This will be the correct code